# how to store array values in internal array?

Tags: php, arrays

i have some array like this

```
$countries=array(country_id->val,country->val,city_id->val,city_name->val)
```

and each country can have multiple cities. now i want have cities of each country in internal array like this:

```
$country=array(country_id->val,country->val,

cities=>array((city_id->val,city_name->val)
,(city_id->val,city_name->val),
 (city_id->val,city_name->val))
```

anybody can help me?

Comment: and array structure for multiple city??

Comment: Certainly you can do that. What is the question with that? Just do it.

Comment: what you  are looking for is a multi dimension array. http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_arrays_multi.asp

Comment: my country array come from database after join country and city table, and i want echo each country and their cities in ul li type, how can i do this? each cities below their country

Comment: please show the result that u r getting.

Answer (score 0):

I'd prefer to create an array for cities separately like this:

```
$cities = array(array(city_id->val, city_name->val),
                array(city_id->val, city_name->val),
                array(city_id->val, city_name->val)
          );//array of cities
```

For more ease of coding, you can try like this:

```
$cities = [
             [city_id->val, city_name->val],
             [city_id->val, city_name->val],
             [city_id->val, city_name->val]
          ];//these brackets represent array in php
```

Now, you can include the array of cities in the array of countries:

```
$country = array(country_id->val, country_name->val, city_id->val,city_name->val, $cities);
```

Moreover, you can do this too if you need country and cities associated to each other:

```
$countries = [
                [
                   country_id->val, 
                   country_name->val, 
                   [
                      city_id->val, 
                      city_name->val
                   ], //first city
                   [
                      city_id->val, 
                      city_name->val
                   ], //second city
                   [
                      city_id->val, 
                      city_name->val
                   ]  //third city
                ], //first country

                [  
                   country_id->val, 
                   country_name->val, 
                   [
                      city_id->val, 
                      city_name->val
                   ], //first city
                   [
                      city_id->val, 
                      city_name->val
                   ], //second city
                   [
                      city_id->val, 
                      city_name->val
                   ]  //third city
                ]  // second country
             ];
```

Therefore creating a three-dimensional array...

Comment: If you want to use arrays more flexibly, then you might use associative arrays which makes it lot easier to retrieve the data.

Answer (score 0):

I would create something like this :

```
$countries = array(
                $country_id->val => array(
                                      "name" => $country_name->val
                                      "cities"=> array(
                                                   city_id->val=>city_name->val, 
                                                   city2_id->val=>city2_name->val)
                                     )
                );
```